# Sweave: How to remove horizontal space in Soutput environments?

Tags: sweave, r

As the following example shows, there is a horizontal space added in the `Soutput` environment. This leads to a non-left-aligned output (see the output of `rnorm()`. I found that this space already exists in "standard R output" (in interactive mode), the question is if it can be avoided somehow?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\begin{document}
\noindent Just some text before the chunk
<<foo>>=
set.seed(1)
rnorm(10)
3 != 4
@
Just some text after the chunk
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not a really LaTeX question -- as you mentioned, the space exists in R output, and it is not caused by the `Soutput` environment.

The reason that the space was added in the output is that you were printing 10 numbers, and R has to reserve one space to make sure the alignment of all lines works well, e.g. the output may have a potential index `[10]` in the last line, which has two characters, while previous indices only has one character, e.g. `[1]`, `[2]`, ...

Note how the number of spaces increases as the number of elements in the vector increases:

```
> options(width = 30)
> 1  # no space
[1] 1
> 1:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 [9]  9 10
> 1:20
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 [9]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
[17] 17 18 19 20
> 1:100  # two spaces now
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6
  [7]   7   8   9  10  11  12
 [13]  13  14  15  16  17  18
 [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24
....
```

There is one solution if you use the [`knitr` package](http://yihui.name/knitr/) instead of Sweave, though. The basic idea is to remove the extra space from the beginning of the lines using an [output hook function](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks).

```
\documentclass{article}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
# modify the default hook to remove spaces before writing output
hook_output = knit_hooks$get('output')
knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
  s = options$rm.spaces
  if (!is.null(s)) x = gsub(sprintf('(^|\n)%s', s), '\\1', x)
  hook_output(x, options)
})
@

\begin{document}
\noindent Just some text before the chunk
<<foo, comment=NA, rm.spaces=' '>>=
set.seed(1)
rnorm(10)
3 != 4
@
Just some text after the chunk
\end{document}
```

To compile the document, use `library(knitr); knit('yourfile.Rnw')` instead of `Sweave('yourfile.Rnw')`.